# Libpq5.6.dylib not found, how do I install 5.7?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, libpq

I run rake db:create and get a libpq not found. I have 5 and 5.7 .. how do I upgrade postgres to use 5.7?

```
rake db:create

rake aborted!
LoadError: dlopen(/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0-preview1/extensions/x86_64-darwin-14/2.2.0/pg-0.17.1/pg_ext.bundle, 9): Library not loaded: /usr/local/lib/libpq.5.6.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0-preview1/extensions/x86_64-darwin-14/2.2.0/pg-0.17.1/pg_ext.bundle
  Reason: image not found - /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0-preview1/extensions/x86_64-darwin-14/2.2.0/pg-0.17.1/pg_ext.bundle

    ls /usr/local/lib/libpq.5.
    libpq.5.7.dylib  libpq.5.dylib
```

Answer (score 0):

Try reinstalling the `pg` Ruby Gem (with `$ gem uninstall pg && gem install pg`). This should recompile the gem using your new version of the Postgres development library.